# Facebook open graph story not show in timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Below is my scenario:

1. Created a custom object type
2. Created a custom action type
3. Created a store type between the custom action and the object.
4. Created a custom object instance
5. Publish a story using the action and the object instance. Also added a mention tag in the published message.

Observe:

1. Login to the tagged person's facebook account, I can see the published story with that person mentioned in the timeline.
2. Login to the current person account (the facebook account, that published the store), I don't see the published story show up in the timeline.

Not sure what is wrong. I'm just testing, the two facebook account are added to the app's tester.

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: is your app live? check out your app settings and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you have explicit share turned off.

> Explicitly Shared - Publish a story directly to Facebook on behalf of a user

To turn this on, you need to

> go the dashboard ->opengraph->actions ->  -> enabled explicitly shared.

To verify this is the actual thing you need : go to activity log and see the privacy setting of the open graph story you just published. You will see the difference i am referring to.